# onReceive maximum thread sleep

Tags: java, android

For an android app, I need to sleep after the onReceive method kicks off.

Through experimenting, I've found that I can do a Thread.sleep for <20 seconds. However, I need to sleep for > 30 seconds. Placing sleeps 1 after another doesn't help (six 5-second sleeps).

(Yes, I know I shouldn't be doing this in a UI thread, it is not a UI thread).

Any thoughts on why there is a maximum Thread.sleep for onReceive and how to get around this?

Comment: read `BroadcastReceiver` docs: *"A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active. This has important repercussions to what you can do in an onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires **asynchronous** operation is **not available**, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the system is ..."*

Answer (score 0):

For scheduling future events, it's best practice to use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), not Thread.sleep(). You cannot use a Timer (or any asynchronous calls) from onReceive() because the process is terminated after onReceive() returns.

As @pskink mentioned, BroadcastReceivers are intended to be short-lived tasks only. Maybe you could post a bit of your design and what you want to do so we could better help you.

The docs recommend

> for longer-running operations you will often use a Service in conjunction with a BroadcastReceiver to keep the containing process active for the entire time of your operation

If you do implement a service, you can use a Timer to achieve a 30 second delay.

Comment: Yes you can't use a Timer from onReceive(), but he should still use a Timer object in his implementation if he requires a task to be run after 30 seconds.

Comment: no,  since after returning from `onReceive` the process can be easily killed by the system

Comment: I expressed my agreement in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `view.postDelyed` in your onReceive. For example

```
public void onReceive(...

  mainView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      setListRecipients(savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(RECIPIENTS));
    }
  }, POST_DELAYED_TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```